# Could CP violation be exploited to violate the second law?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, cp-violation

I don't understand well CP-violation, but since it introduces a microscopic irreversible process, couldn't it be somehow exploited to decrease entropy? For instance, if we could somehow use it to bias average particle movement in a particular direction I suppose it could be used to extract work.

Comment: Not necessarily. Attempting the reverse process could still release energy into the system even if the end result is not reversible.

Comment: For irreversibility to emerge in our fundamental laws, you would at least need CPT violation.